# Getting an artifact from dockerimage using azure devops?

Tags: azure, docker, image, containers, artifact

Please how do i get an artifact from dockerfile using azure devops

I built the dockerimage using azure devops but I am having issues saving it as an artifact

Answer (score 0):

You can add manually commands and save it as an artifact also. We recommend that you can use this to upload the docker Image as an artifact, this is also mentioned in the article and steps to do **[this](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/container-image-promotion-across-environments-build-artifact-5887)**